# Pagination shifting in review, on reload

Tags: feature-request, bug, review, pagination

When reviewing answers, on any page of `/review`, using the pagination causes the page to reload, but continues to advance the offset.

For example, if there are between 15 and 30 questions/answers in a specific tab of review (under the setting for 15 questions/answers per page), and after reviewing all 15 on the current page, visiting the pagination tab for page 2 will result in the page reloading, thus hiding all recently reviewed items, bringing you to a blank `/review` page.

Related:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42511/favourites-pagination-breaks-if-removing-one-of-15n1

Comment: It seems this has been fixed, as /review now has two options: Non-random sorting with pagination, and random sorting with the standard "Get 30 more" link.

Answer (score 2):

I'm offering a bit of a non answer here, which explains why this happens and possible approaches to fix.

Review eliminates already reviewed items from the list ... if you already reviewed 15 items and head to page 2 (with 15 per page) we eliminate the 15 you already reviewed from the list and head to page 3.

To get pagination to work properly we would need to also track the post id of the first item **you think** is on page 2 and then take you to the page that starts with it.

It does get complicated though ... what happens when you review 7 items with gaps and then head to page 2?

Similar pagination bugs exist everywhere on the site, "page 2" is always calculated when you click on it. So for example ... go to questions sorted by activity ... wait 10 minutes hit page 2. You are not going to get the same "page 2" you would have gotten 10 minutes ago.

---

I have been thinking a bit about the pagination issue on review and am tempted to go with the "infinite list" with a "get more items" in the bottom. (that pulls in more items as you review stuff, so you never really need to paginate)

Comment: I agree - it's not something that can just be fixed in the blink of an eye, since it's more than just a program bug, it's a logical problem - an infinite list/"get more items" method might be a good way to go about that.

Comment: I think infinite scrolling would be a much better way to handle this situation in Review since the "pages" are ephemeral at best.

Answer (score 1):

**The "pages" of reviews should really use [Infinite Scrolling](http://uxmovement.com/navigation/infinite-scrolling-best-practices/) rather than pagination**. Since the pages change constantly (for all users, not just one!) the **page numbers are meaningless**, especially since the posts you just reviewed were probably just removed from the list. It would make much more sense to use an infinite scroll paradigm and continue to load "older" review items at the bottom, loading them only once the user hits the bottom of a page.

This avoids the paging issue and it removes the clicks required for paging, in addition it avoids the issue of "newer" content messing with the "pages"; you could instead always load only review items after the timestamp of the last item in the current displayed list. This way if I wanted to see the new review items I could instead refresh and the top items on the page would always be the most recent review items at the time of page load.

[Twitter](https://twitter.com/) remains a great example of Infinite Scrolling, hitting the bottom of the page loads content after the last visible item, and new content is available at the top in a "display X new messages" item that loads when new items are posted. For the review page I don't see the "new review items" feature as a necessity but it would be a nice bonus.